# How can I do to convert a valuesqueryset to a JSON with datetime?

Tags: python, json, django, python-3.x

Hello I am trying to convert a list to JSON, here is my code :

```
json.dumps(myList)
```

But the problem is that in my valuesqueryset I have some datetime ...

Do you have any ideas to solve this problem ?

Thank you !

Comment: It would help if you gave was an example of your `valuequeryset` list.  You can iterate through your list and type cast all datetimes to strings.

Answer (score 0):

Django provides a native DjangoJSONEncoder serializer that deals with this kind of properly.

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#djangojsonencoder

```
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder

return json.dumps(
  item,
  sort_keys=True,
  indent=1,
  cls=DjangoJSONEncoder
)
```

Comment: I tried but I get this : `{TypeError}<QuerySet ...` It is strainge because I tried with `serializers.serialize()` and it works but the problem is that I cannot use `serializers.serialize()` because I have foreign key ...

Comment: Can you add an example of your list?

Comment: DateTime `A string of the form YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ or YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sss+HH:MM as defined in ECMA-262. `